# concatenate multiple columns based on index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As a follow up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021730/can-pandas-handle-variable-length-whitespace-as-column-delimeters), I would like to concatenate a number of columns based on their index but I am encountering some problems. In this example I get an Attribute error related to the map function.  Help around this error would be appreciated as would code that does the equivalent concatenation of columns.

```
    #data
    df = DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c'], 'B':['d','e','f'], 'C':['concat','me','yo'], 'D':['me','too','tambien']})

    #row function to concat rows with index greater than 2
    def cnc(row):
        temp = []
        for x in range(2,(len(row))):
            if row[x] != None:
                temp.append(row[x])
        return map(concat, temp)

    #apply function per row
    new = df.apply(cnc,axis=1)

    #Expected Output
    new

    concat me
    me too
    yo tambien
```

thanks,
zach cp

Comment: Please post the error you receive, as well as your expected output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> df = DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c'], 'B':['d','e','f'], 'C':['concat','me','yo'], 'D':['me','too','tambien']})
>>> df
   A  B       C        D
0  a  d  concat       me
1  b  e      me      too
2  c  f      yo  tambien
>>> df.columns[2:]
Index([C, D], dtype=object)
>>> df[df.columns[2:]]
        C        D
0  concat       me
1      me      too
2      yo  tambien
>>> [' '.join(row) for row in df[df.columns[2:]].values]
['concat me', 'me too', 'yo tambien']
>>> df["new"] = [' '.join(row) for row in df[df.columns[2:]].values]
>>> df
   A  B       C        D         new
0  a  d  concat       me   concat me
1  b  e      me      too      me too
2  c  f      yo  tambien  yo tambien
```

If you have `None` objects floating around, you could handle that too.  For example:

```
>>> df["C"][1] = None
>>> df
   A  B       C        D
0  a  d  concat       me
1  b  e    None      too
2  c  f      yo  tambien
>>> rows = df[df.columns[2:]].values
```

In near-English:

```
>>> new = [' '.join(word for word in row if word is not None) for row in rows]
>>> new
['concat me', 'too', 'yo tambien']
```

Using `filter`:

```
>>> new = [' '.join(filter(None, row)) for row in rows]
>>> new
['concat me', 'too', 'yo tambien']
```

etc.  You could do it in one line but I think it's clearer to separate it.

Comment: Can you also eliminate None values using the list comprehension?

Comment: note that support for `filter(None, iterable)` ceased in Python 3, need to do `filter(bool, iterable)` there