# possible inconsistency in text handling of pandas read_table() function

Tags: python, pandas

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021730/can-pandas-handle-variable-length-whitespace-as-column-delimeters), I found out that pandas `read_table()` function can handle variable-lenth whitespace as a delimiter if you use the `read_table('datafile', sep=r'\s*')` construction. While this works great for many of my files, it does not work for others despite being highly similar.

EDIT:
I had posted examples that could not replicate the problem when other tried. So I am posting links to the original files for [AY907538](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1803062/AY907538.hmmdomtblout) and [AY942707](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1803062/AY942707.hmmdomtblout) as well as leaving the error message that I cannot manage to solve.

```
## filename:AY942707
# this will load with no problem
data = read_table('AY942707.hmmdomtblout', header=None, skiprows=3, sep=r'\s*')

## filename: AY907538
data = read_table('AY907538.hmmdomtblout', header=None, skiprows=3, sep=r'\s*')
```

which will generate the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-131d10d1fb1d> in <module>()
      2 
      3 #temp = get_dataset('AY907538.hmmdomtblout')
----> 4 data = read_table('AY907538.hmmdomtblout', header=None, skiprows=3, sep=r'\s*')
      5 #data = read_table('AY942707.hmmdomtblout', header=None, skiprows=3, sep=r'\s*')

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in read_table(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, header, index_col, names, skiprows, na_values, thousands, comment, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, nrows, iterator, chunksize, skip_footer, converters, verbose, delimiter, encoding, squeeze)
    282     kwds['encoding'] = None
    283 
--> 284     return _read(TextParser, filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    285 
    286 @Appender(_read_fwf_doc)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(cls, filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    189         return parser
    190 
--> 191     return parser.get_chunk()
    192 
    193 @Appender(_read_csv_doc)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in get_chunk(self, rows)
    779             msg = ('Expecting %d columns, got %d in row %d' %
    780                    (col_len, zip_len, row_num))
--> 781             raise ValueError(msg)
    782 
    783         data = dict((k, v) for k, v in izip(self.columns, zipped_content))

ValueError: Expecting 26 columns, got 28 in row 6
```

Comment: Try to reduce your sample data to something smaller (ideally a single row) that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @BrenBarn. Brought it down to just a few entries as I wanted to leave a few for comparison. The bug entry says the sixth row is the issue. Do you think the shorter value - 4.6 - in the i-Evalue could be the issue?

Comment: Works for me.  So ISTM either something got lost during the posting process or my copying process, or we're using different `pandas` versions.  [Mine says 0.8.1, but I can't remember if I'm using a checked-out copy or not.]

Comment: hmmm. Let me check my version and also copy the data I posted to see if I can replicate the error.

Comment: @DMS thanks for checking the data. I am 0.8. as well. But when I copy/paste the webpage data I posted back into a text file and read it in, I have no problem either. Do you think this could point to something to do with hard-returns?

Comment: added links to the original files so they can be downloaded.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce this.  Unfortunately the only way I can get around it is very hacky.  Hopefully someone else can come up with something clever (if not, maybe it's worth making a pull request to Wes McKinney.)

Comment: @DSM. Thanks for sticking with this problem. I am happy to bring it to Wes' attention but I am not clear where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last field `description of target` in both files holds multiple words. Since white space  is used as seperator, `description of target` is not treated as a single column by read_table. Each word in this field is in a different column. In `AY942707` the first `description of target` holds more words than on all of the other lines, this is not the case in AY907538. `read_table` determines the number of columns from the first line and all following lines should have equal or less number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I thought that finding the answer may prove helpful to pandas but I think in this case a little pre-munging before loading into pandas is the best way to go. Thanks again.