# What is the best way to read columnar data from .txt file which includes complex numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a text file of the form shown in attached image.[image: 5-column data. Colum 0,1: Position coord x,y. Column 3,4,5: Complex fields]

with almost 200 data points.

How to read them efficiently in form of arrays such that a=array([2,3,...]); d=array([4+5j,3+1j,....])?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your text is formatted in a way that `genfromtxt` can handle it without problems.

Ignoring the column names and such for now, a sample line would be:

```
In [235]: txt = """-1.99 -1.99 1.07+0.165j"""
```

Specify `dtype` to be float and complex for the appropriate columns:

```
In [240]: data = np.genfromtxt([txt,txt],dtype=(float,float,complex))
In [241]: data
Out[241]: 
array([(-1.99, -1.99, 1.07+0.165j), (-1.99, -1.99, 1.07+0.165j)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<c16')])
```

The result is a structured array (1d).  Fields are accessed by name:

```
In [242]: data['f0']
Out[242]: array([-1.99, -1.99])
In [243]: data['f2']
Out[243]: array([1.07+0.165j, 1.07+0.165j])
```

The pandas csv reader is faster, but with only 200 data points, I don't think speed will be much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas.

If the space between columns is a tab, then `sep='\t'`, otherwise use the solution from [Can pandas handle variable-length whitespace as column delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021730/can-pandas-handle-variable-length-whitespace-as-column-delimiters)

Assuming it is a tab, the code to extract the third column of complex numbers is something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t',skiprows=3)
df.columns = [f'col_{i}' for i in range(len(df.columns))]

column_2_complex_values = df.col_2.map(complex).values # this is a numpy array
```