# Read tab-delimited fields with pandas when some lines have more than one tab

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a tab-separated text file using pandas. The file looks like this:

[data file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hH4G.png)

```
14.38   14.21   0.8951  5.386   3.312   2.462   4.956   1
14.69   14.49   0.8799  5.563   3.259   3.586   5.219   1
14.11   14.12   0.8911  5.422   3.302   2.723           5       1
```

Some lines have extra tabs. If I use `read_csv` or `read_fwf` and specify `sep='\t'`. I get results that look like this:

```
0   15.26\t14.84\t0.871\t5.763\t3.312\t2.221\t5.22\t1
1   14.88\t14.57\t0.8811\t5.554\t3.333\t1.018\t4.9
```

Do you have any suggestions as to what parameters I could specify to deal with this problem?

Solution:

`use pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: Try read_csv(delim_whitespace=True)

Comment: I do not know what the problem is. Is it that you want the results to contain \t\t when there are two tabs in the data? Also, if you post the data as a string instead of a .png I can more easily debug on my end.

Comment: @Vaishali, Thank you very much! That works!

Answer (score 7):

Pandas read_csv is very versatile, you can use it with delim_whitespace = True to handle variable number of whitespaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Option 2: Use separator argument

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t+')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
parsed_csv_txt = pd.read_csv("tabbed.txt",sep="\t")
print(parsed_csv_txt)
```

On this file:

```
a   b   c   d   e
14.69   2452    982 234 12
14.11   5435    234     12
16.63   1       12  66
```

I get:

```
       a     b      c      d   e
0  14.69  2452  982.0  234.0  12
1  14.11  5435  234.0    NaN  12
2  16.63     1    NaN   12.0  66
```

Are there any issues with the output that we see here?

**If you would like a different output such as:**

```
       a     b    c    d     e
0  14.69  2452  982  234  12.0
1  14.11  5435  234   12   NaN
2  16.63     1   12   66   NaN
```

Use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
parsed_csv_txt = pd.read_csv("tabbed.txt",delim_whitespace=True)
print(parsed_csv_txt)
```

**Note**

For a longer discussion around the topic of variable amounts of whitespace between values check out this discussion: [Can pandas handle variable-length whitespace as column delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021730/can-pandas-handle-variable-length-whitespace-as-column-delimiters)